# Solr eDismax Search - Prioritize phrase over individual words

Tags: solr

I am trying to use the eDismax Query Parser with the following requirements where a search query can be intepreted as a phrase and also individual words, but where phrase takes precedence over individual words.

**Example:**

**Search query:** We are cool

**Results should be:**

- Documents fields with phrase 'we are cool' appearing top of list
- Documents where fields comprises of either 'we', 'are', 'cool' where highest number of occurences take precedence.

How would I go about implementing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way: use pf param boosting for that, check the doc [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thepf(PhraseFields)Parameter)

So for example, adding this (if you had those two fields):

```
q=We are cool&pf=mytitle^10 mydescription
```

Comment: Hi @Persimmonium , what if I want only higher scoring for 'phrase' over individual words in phrase, regardless of fields? Thanks

Comment: you always have to specify some field in Solr. There is a config for default field df.

Comment: Ok understood. However may I know what will be my 'q' in this case? I tried "We are cool" and it only returns exact phrases but not results which have words inside this phrase. It will be better if you can provide the whole query altogether with the other params. Thanks

Comment: added q param, maybe you were using quotes, if your q uses quotes, it will require the exact phrase to be found

Comment: I tried doing it without quotes, and top results are 'We Are Cool' titles, however there is a result without either 'We', 'Are', or 'Cool' appearing within top 10 results. There are also results with 1 'We' having higher scores than those with more incidences of 'We' and 'Are' in total. 'Title' field is a multivalued field in this case as well.

Comment: a result without any of the terms in the query is impossible unless you have other things going on (synonyms, stemming etc). Debug your analysis chain in the analysis page.